# Guess 100 bits of md5 hash

Tags: md5

I found the following challenge on a wargames site:

A 16 byte string is randomly generated and hashed with md5 => HashRandom

Next, the following happens in an infinite loop:

1. user is prompted for a 16 byte input
2. input is hashed => HashUser
3. HashUser is compared with HashRandom and the number of matching bits is displayed

The goal is to get at least 100 matching bits.

A couple of observations:

1. The initial random string is generated using lowercase/uppercase characters, numbers and characters like `.,"...`
2. usually, for any user input string like `AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA` I get between 50 and 70 matching bits

To get a better understanding on what happens behind the scenes, I did some reading on md5 and Wang's attack ( http://merlot.usc.edu/csac-f06/papers/Wang05a.pdf ) + other papers related to it. Based on that, here are some notes:

- My input will look like this (UI - user input - bytes I can control):

> ```
> m0  - 0xUIUIUIUI
> m1  - 0xUIUIUIUI
> m2  - 0xUIUIUIUI
> m3  - 0xUIUIUIUI
> m4  - 0x00000080 - initial padding with 1 + 0's 
> m5  - 0x00000000
> m6  - 0x00000000
> m7  - 0x00000000
> m8  - 0x00000000
> m9  - 0x00000000
> m10 - 0x00000000
> m11 - 0x00000000
> m12 - 0x00000000
> m13 - 0x00000000
> m14 - 0x00000000
> m15 - 0x00000080 - input size - 128 bits - 16 bytes
> ```

- Wang talks about a differential attack used to generate messages that collide under md5. I read that hoping it would give me some hints, however it can't really be applied for this challenge. The method described uses two 512 bit input blocks per message. It also imposes restrictions on bytes I can't control.
- The only breakthrough I had with this is the ability to control the hash function after the first round (however, this is trivial and I don't think it can help me)
- Because I can get the matching number of bits for how many strings I want, I can get an idea on how the hash of the random generated string looks like. Since I only need 100 bits, I don't need the hash to mach 100%. Basically, if I can control half of the hash (64 bits), with some luck I can get 36 other random bits to match.
- On the fourth round of the md5 algorithm, the 63rd operation (so right before the final value is calculated) involves `m2` (which I control):

`Q63 = Q62 + Q59 + I (Q62, Q61, Q60) + m2 + 0x2ad7d2bb) <<< 15`

`Q63` will also have an effect on `Q64`.

This might allow me to intervene on the last 64 bits of the hash function; however, any change on `m2` will impact the way in which `Q63` and `Q64` are calculated so I'm not sure if this can help.

Any ideas or suggested reading that could point me in the right direction? (GPU + brute force is the last thing on the list - I'm hoping there's another way to do it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A 3 minute running time on my laptop (running Java) already gave me a bit string where 99 bits are identical. It might be that you're overthinking this.

This sounds like a classical proof of work that you're supposed to do. As it is unlikely that there are any shortcuts I guess you'll have to break it brute-force. And as is it a gaming site, the faster GPU probably wins.

MD5 still has pre-image resistance of over $2^{123}$, with the specific attack mentioned [here](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-3-642-01001-9_8). You won't get far with just finding collisions as the pre-image seems to be (unknown) and given.

---

Just computing on a laptop gives, comparing with a hash of all zero's:

```
100 : 00000000000000000000000625b4aa69 -> 0740a0a42a0074920018000008308212
```

only just over 26,000,000,000 (16 billion for the US, 16 milliard for the rest of us) hashes required; the hexadecimal representation of the value as 16 byte integer is used as input.

Took some time but nothing major, unoptimized, single threaded Java code, running on a downclocked i7 laptop. On a fast machine with semi-optimized, multi-threaded code expect a 16 times improvement minimum.

Comment: I was hoping for a more elegant solution to this. Oh well, at least now I know some of the internals of md5

Comment: I understand. But unless you can somehow control the initial input to the   hash you can only attack using pre-image attacks, not collision attacks.

Comment: You compared with a hash of all zeros. This simplifies the problem. Using a "normal" hash value as a target, I'm at 1.7 billion hashes and only got one 98 bit match.

Comment: The hash output is indistinguishable from random; it doesn't matter if you compare with all zeros or any other number. Nor does it say much how many 98 or 99's you get. You could get none and then 100 with still a relatively high probability.

Comment: You're right. My bad. I have some catching up to do on probability theory.

Comment: Finally got 100 after ~ 45 billion

Comment: I'm wondering if the average time would be $2^{(100 - 128 / 2)} / 2 = 34,359,738,368$. That would make sense I guess.